# Rails testing: "No route matches" for custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I have following route:

```
GET    /confirm/:token(.:format)  Confirmations#confirm
```

Controller:

```
class ConfirmationsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /confirm/<token>
  def confirm
    @user = User.find_by_email_token(params[:token])
    if @user
      @user.confirmed = true
      @user.email_token = nil
      @user.save!
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to root_url, flash: { success: "Welcome <#{@user.email}>, your address has been verified." }
    elsif
      redirect_to root_url, flash: { error: "Error: could not find matching user record." }
    end
  end
end
```

And this simple `confirmations_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ConfirmationsController do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email_token: "some_token") }

  describe "Get confirm" do
    it "confirms user with valid email_token" do
      get :confirm, token: "some_token"
      assigns(:user).should eq(user)
      user.reload.email_token.should be_nil
    end

    it "does not confirm user with invalid email_token"
  end
end
```

but it fails:

```
  1) ConfirmationsController Get confirm confirms user with valid email_token
     Failure/Error: get :confirm, token: "some_token"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:token=>"some_token", :controller=>"confirmations", :action=>"confirm"}
     # ./spec/controllers/confirmations_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Anyone see what (could be multiple things) I screwed up?

BTW- I'm using a `get` request here (as opposed to `put`) because it's being initiated from a text based email so we can't, to my understanding, use a `put` request...

Comment: If you change `get :confirm, token: "some_token"` to `get '/confirm/some_token'` does it work?

Comment: @mccannf - nope. `Failure/Error: get 'confirm/some_token'` `No route matches {:controller=>"confirmations", :action=>"confirm/some_token"}`

Comment: @mccannf - same problem with `'/confirm/some_token'`: `No route matches {:controller=>"confirmations", :action=>"/confirm/some_token"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rake routes, `Confirmations` should not have a capital letter.

Can you define the route like so in `config/routes.rb`:

```
match '/confirm/:token' => 'confirmations#confirm'
```